# how can i resolve Invalid property 'class.module.classLoader.resources' of bean class

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

i am debugging a spring mvc web project with jdk 11,springboot 2.5.12 and external tomcat 8.5,it report the errors below when i post a request to test spring beans(Parameter binding),but i found the method init() in class org.apache.catalina.WebResourceRoot(it extends Lifecycle),how can i resolve it ?

```
 ERROR 31356 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.b.w.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter  : Forwarding to error page from request [/demo] due to exception [Invalid property 'class.module.classLoader.resources' of bean class [java.lang.Module]: Could not instantiate property type [org.apache.catalina.WebResourceRoot] to auto-grow nested property path; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.catalina.WebResourceRoot.<init>()]
    org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException: Invalid property 'class.module.classLoader.resources' of bean class [java.lang.Module]: Could not instantiate property type [org.apache.catalina.WebResourceRoot] to auto-grow nested property path; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.catalina.WebResourceRoot.<init>()
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.newValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:923) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.createDefaultPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setDefaultValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:874) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getNestedPropertyAccessor(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:846) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyAccessorForPropertyPath(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:820) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyAccessorForPropertyPath(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:821) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyAccessorForPropertyPath(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:821) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyAccessorForPropertyPath(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:821) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:256) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:104) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.applyPropertyValues(DataBinder.java:856) ~[spring-context-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.doBind(DataBinder.java:751) ~[spring-context-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder.doBind(WebDataBinder.java:198) ~[spring-web-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestDataBinder.bind(ServletRequestDataBinder.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.bindRequestParameters(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:158) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:171) ~[spring-web-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:122) ~[spring-web-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:179) ~[spring-web-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:146) ~[spring-web-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.78]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.78]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:8.5.78]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.78]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.78]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.78]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.78]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.78]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.78]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:126) ~[spring-boot-2.5.12.jar:2.5.12]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:64) ~[spring-boot-2.5.12.jar:2.5.12]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:101) ~[spring-boot-2.5.12.jar:2.5.12]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:119) ~[spring-boot-2.5.12.jar:2.5.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.78]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.78]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.78]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.78]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.78]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.78]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.78]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.78]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.78]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.78]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.78]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:367) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.78]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:639) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.78]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.78]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:882) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.78]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1647) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.78]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.78]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-util.jar:8.5.78]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-util.jar:8.5.78]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-util.jar:8.5.78]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.catalina.WebResourceRoot.<init>()
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3349) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2553) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.newValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:914) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        ... 70 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Well I really hope you aren't trying to set `class.module.classLoader.resources` this property! If you are you shouldn't and you should be glad you get this error (as it is an attack vector to execute Java code through Serialization)!.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: For learning purposes only, looking forward to solving